# How to count stores in cache analysis of matrix multiplication

Tags: computer-architecture, arrays, cpu-cache, matrix

I'm trying to understand cache misses/iter and came across this that I couldn't understand or reason out.

For **ijk** iteration, my slides say that there are 2 loads and 0 stores.

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
  for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
   sum = 0.0;
   for (k=0; k<n; k++)
     sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
   c[i][j] = sum;
  } 
}
```

Similarly, for **kij** iteration, my slides say that there are 2 loads and 1 store.

```
for (k=0; k<n; k++) {
 for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
  r = a[i][k];
  for (j=0; j<n; j++)
   c[i][j] += r * b[k][j];
 }
}
```

And for **jki** iteration, my slides say that there are 2 loads and 1 store.

```
for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
 for (k=0; k<n; k++) {
   r = b[k][j];
   for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * r;
 }
}
```

I believe the loads are counted in each case when data is referred to by calling arr[x][x] on the right hand side of the arithmetic evaluation, which would make two in each case. But how are the stores counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the analysis assumes that integer variables are stored in registers, whereas array elements have to be loaded from and stored to memory. The point you've missed is that the statemnt `X += Y` requires reading `X` and then writing the new value of `X`.

```
sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
```

This **load**s `a[i][k]`, **load**s `b[k][j]`, multiplies them, reads `sum`, adds `sum` and the product and writes the result to `sum`. Two loads, no stores.

```
c[i][j] += r * b[k][j];
```

This **load**s `b[k][j]`, reads `r`, multiplies them, **load**s `c[i][j]`, adds the product to it and **store**s the new value of `c[i][j]`. Two loads, one store.

```
c[i][j] += a[i][k] * r;
```

This is essentially the same as the previous case.

Comment: Aha! So when when you're writing back to the sum in the first case, you are essentially "storing" it in the registers, and they do not count as "stores" since they are not technically stored in the memory?

Comment: @Jeremy I think that's what's going on, yes.